# I cant get a plain Text with headless Wordpress and Graphql

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, graphql, graphiql

I am building a frontend with React. I use Headless wordpress iwth GraphiQL and WooCommerce.
Now i created some products with a shortDescription. But when i fetch these products i get the description as a HTML-formatted string.
[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oblzN.png)

With the playground in Wordpress i can add the format attribute to the shortDiscription:
It looks like this:
[Wordpress Playground](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOItn.png)

Ok this is working in the playground. My output is plain/raw text without HTML Tags. When i copy this query and execute it with react my output is "null".
After removing the format attribute in the query in React i get the output but again in HTML Tags.

Comment: don't link external images ... most probably by user rights (admin for graphiql, not logged in react)

Comment: @xadm I tried it with full rights, are not the problem :(

Comment: are you sure? `viewer` type/properties queried?

Comment: @xadm Well with the Bearer Token Authorization it works thanks. :). Do you know how can i access this data with every user?

Answer (score 1):

`wpgraphql` **makes use of general WP user capabilities to control visibility of types and properties.**

Not all values visible in `graphiql` (embedded in admin area) are publicly available. **A public page displaying content works with not registered user rights while graphiql works with administrator capabilities.** Raact/apollo should at least include credentials (for cookie) or use token - for logged in users.

AFAICR for public content you can overwrite `admin's private` flag using 'graphql_data_is_private' filter. It looks like:

```
function add_graphql_private_visibility_filter($is_private, $model_name, $data, $visibility, $owner, $current_user)
{
  // start with UNSAFE 'return false;' here, then make more granular checks
  if ('PostObject' === $model_name) {
    // if ('CPT' === $data->post_type) {
        if(.....
          ...
            return false;
  ...
  return $is_private;
  
 add_filter('graphql_data_is_private', add_graphql_private_visibility_filter', 10, 6);
```

Comment: Where do i have to add this function?

Comment: functions / plugin / yourTheme/functions , like any custom code?